# Does Spring support 'dependency injection by convention' similar to Grails?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring only autowires beans to fields/setters/constructors which are annotated with @Resource, @Autowired (not considering Java Config and XML configuration).

Is there a way to configure Spring to automatically guess where the @Resource/ @Autowired annotations could be placed and do the autowiring based on that?

Here's how it works in Grails:

```
class BookController {
    def bookService
    …
}
```

How can I make it working in Spring?

```
@Controller
public class BookController {
    BookService bookService
    …
}
```

Comment: Spring Framework 4.3, and therefore Spring Boot 1.4, will allow you to use constructor injection without `@Autowired` when the class has a single constructor. See https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3 for further details

Comment: That sounds great. I'm looking forward Spring Boot 1.4 now